# Deserialize external library classes with a builder method as a constructor

Tags: java, jackson, json-deserialization

I have a class like this:

```
class MyClass {
    CustomList<String> list = ListUtils.createCustomList();
}
```

Where `interface CustomList implements java.util.List` so it cannot be deserialized with a constructor. Instead there is a `class ListUtils` which creates an implementation instance. Both the interface and the utility class are in an external library so I can't annotate them.

How can I tell Jackson that when encountering `CustomList` it should invoke `ListUtils.createCustomList()` instead of a constructor? Is there a mixin configuration, a mapping I can specify from type to construction method, or a custom deserializer I need to write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 issues here, the first of which is how to tell Jackson to use a static method of another class `ListUtils` to create an instance of `CustomList` class. There is `@JsonCreator` that you could use on a static method of `CustomList` or through a mix in. Unfortunately, you can't use that on `ListUtils`. There is a an [open issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1820) for that.

Until the above request is implemented / released you have to create a custom deserializer. A skeleton implementation of such a deserializer would look something like this:

```
class ListDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<CustomList> {
    @Override
    public CustomList deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext c) throws IOException {
        return ListUtils.createCustomList();
    }
}
```

Extend this method with other initialization steps, e.g. to parse elements with `JsonParser` and add them to the list before returning it. See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20529826/1413133). You can specify this deserializer to be used without any annotations on the `ObjectMapper`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(CustomList.class, new ListDeserializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

Comment: Thanks. About populating the list after construction, can't I tell Jackson to just populate the list as it would anyway? All I want to change is the initialization step and then continue as usual.

Comment: Found the answer I was looking for and marked as duplicate, but this answer is correct anyway.